# How can I convert an object to bytes or something else that can be sent over LoRa in Python?

Tags: python, object, byte, pickle, lora

I created an object like the one below

```
class POWER:
    def __init__(self, voltage, current, wattage):
        self.voltage = voltage
        self.current = current
        self.wattage = wattage
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            "<Voltage: {:.3} V, Current: {:.5} A, Wattage: {:.5} W>"
            .format(self.voltage, self.current, self.wattage)
        )
```

I then tried to send the object in a variety of ways over LoRa

```
rfm9x.send(POWER(1,1,1))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 467, in <module>
  File "/lib/adafruit_rfm9x.py", line 693, in send
TypeError: object of type 'POWER' has no len()
```

```
rfm9x.send(bytes(POWER(1,1,1)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 467, in <module>
TypeError: 'POWER' object is not iterable
```

The only thing that was able to convert it even somewhat was

```
rfm9x.send(pickle.dumps(POWER(1,1,1)))
```

However, it just sends

```
b'<Voltage: 1 V, Current: 1 A, Wattage: 1 W>'
```

When it converts like this, it does not seem like you can unpickle it.  Am I overlooking something in the construction of these objects? Am I not converting them properly? or is it not possible to convert, transmit and decode the values of an object?

Comment: How did you see what it sends?

Comment: I have a second LoRa setup, additionally I print out everything it sends.  On the second LoRa I tried to unpickle it; however, it seems to be that line of text converted to bytes, not the object.

Comment: You mean on the receiving end, after unpickling you got `b'<Voltage: 1 V, Current: 1 A, Wattage: 1 W>'`? Or before unpickling?